# Mostrar mensaje de un alert en pagina ya creada php

Tags: php, javascript, alert

Estoy buscando un código para contar resultado de una búsqueda en una tabla y encontré un script para la tabla muy sencillo, pero el resultado es un alert. Es :

```
<script language="javascript">
// contar busqueda en la tabla
onload = function countRows(){
       var rows = document.getElementById('mi-tabla').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows.length;

       alert(rows);
       
}

</script>
```

Esto genera el resultado en un alert...y lo que quiero es que,  ese resultado, me lo guarde en una variable en php para ponerlo con un "echo" en la página, en una parte especifica. Como puedo hacerlo? Gracias!!!

Comment: Por qué no utilizas `mysqli_num_rows()` directamente con la consulta en php?

Answer (score 0):

No se puede interactuar con el PHP que genera la pagina una vez que se renderisa esta.

Lo que puedes hacer es modificar el DOM generado, para ello solo tienes que obtener el elemento con getElementById, querySelector o querySelectorAll

Una vez que lo obtienes este tendra la propiedad  innerHTML

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'demo';
```